# Installing AntiX's WMs on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, window-manager, ubuntu-mate, window-management

I am not able to find an answer to this question, so I hope somebody will help me out.  I currently use [Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 LTS](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntumate) and love it.  I have it set up perfectly to fit my needs.  I also frequently check DistroWatch to see what other distros are being developed and released out of sheer curiosity.

Recently, I found the new beta release of [AntiX 16-b5](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=antix) and gave it a shot in VirtualBox.  I am so impressed and I'd like to know if there's a way I could add all the [Window Managers and combination Window Managers](http://oi64.tinypic.com/2z3nbes.jpg) that AntiX uses with my Ubuntu-Mate system.

In case the link above did not work, here's a list of the WMs:

- Rox-Fluxbox
- Space-Fluxbox
- Fluxbox
- Min-Fluxbox
- Rox-IceWM
- Space-IceWM
- IceWM
- Min-IceWM
- Rox-JWM
- Space-JWM
- JWM
- Min-JWM
- Herbstluftwm

Is this possible?  If so, how can I go about doing it?

Thanks a lot!

~ Ev

Comment: Look at `apt search "window manager"` for what easily available. Then use `sudo apt-get install`. Or do you have something else in mind? The ones that aren't listed maybe in ppas or available via searching the internet with a _caveat emptor_

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you cannot. Not easily, at least.

The the items in your list aren't discrete, separate, window managers. Item #1 for instance (rox-fluxbox) relies on an antix script to both initiate a fluxbox (window manager) session and set rox as desktop manager. The underlying script also sets rox-filer as preferred file manager and handles any session autostart apps.

For use on top of your existing ubuntu, to achieve all those login choices you would, AT A MINIMUM, need to install "icewm" and "fluxbox" (and fbpanel) and "jwm"... then install the rox-desktop package (IIRC, includes rox-filer file manager) and install "spacefm" file manager. Who can guess whether ubuntu repository has suitable versions of these packages, plus suitable versions of the packages they depend on?

If you manage to successfully find/install all of the above WMs etc., you'll still need to tweak their configs to achieve autostarts... and "fluxbox" knows nothing about "rox". That's where the custom (antix) script(s) come into play. IIRC, those scripts are contained within, and installed by, the package "antix-desktop-defaults" which would have been preinstalled in the antix linux ISO. If you're interested, you can browse/study the content of those scripts by visiting github dot com slash antiX-Linux (note: capitalized here to match the URL/path as exists at github)